# How to compute $\langle \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle$ given $\log (\vec{v} + 1)$ and $\log (\vec{w} + 1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

I am dealing with a single cell expression dataset. The dataset forms a $m \times n$ count matrix where each cell is a row and each gene is a column. Each element in the raw count matrix is a non-negative integer. By convention, the matrix is normalized by applying $\log(x + 1)$ element-wise. The offset is needed as many genes have zero count. I wish to compare the similarity of two cells which requires the dot product $\langle \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle$.

How should I compute the dot product given $\log(\vec{v} + 1)$ and $\log(\vec{w} + 1)$?

An idea I have is to compute the following:

$$
\begin{align}\langle \vec{1}, \exp(\log(\vec{v} + 1) + \log(\vec{w} + 1))\rangle - \langle \vec{1}, \vec{v}\rangle - \langle \vec{1}, \vec{w}\rangle - n & = \sum_i^n (v_i + 1)(w_i + 1) - \sum_i^n v_i - \sum_i^n w_i - n \\
&= \sum_i^n (v_i w_i + v_i + w_i + 1) - \sum_i^n v_i - \sum_i^n w_i - n \\
&= \sum_i^n v_i w_i \\
&= \langle \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle
\end{align}
$$

So I implemented my idea and the $\langle \exp(\log(\vec{v} + 1)) - 1, \exp(\log(\vec{w} + 1)) -1 \rangle$ proposed by @VHarisop.

```
def dot1p(v_log1p, w_log1p) -> float:
    v = np.expm1(v_log1p)
    w = np.expm1(w_log1p)

    # Compute the other terms in the equation
    vw_sum_exp = np.exp(v_log1p + w_log1p)  # exp(log(v + 1) + log(w + 1))
    return np.sum(vw_sum_exp) - np.sum(v) - np.sum(w) - len(v)

def npdot1p(v_log1p: np.ndarray, w_log1p: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return np.dot(np.expm1(v_log1p), np.expm1(w_log1p))
```

For a $n$-dimensional random vector between $[0, 1)$, it seems that $\langle \exp(\log(\vec{v} + 1)) - 1, \exp(\log(\vec{w} + 1)) -1 \rangle$ is the faster solution with negligible error. Since there is only one multiplication for each pair of elements, it should indeed be the case.

```
Size: 10, Time (dot1p): 0.000053 seconds, Time (npdot1p): 0.000013 seconds, Difference: 7.632330e-16
Size: 100, Time (dot1p): 0.000029 seconds, Time (npdot1p): 0.000010 seconds, Difference: 1.084507e-16
Size: 1000, Time (dot1p): 0.000258 seconds, Time (npdot1p): 0.000024 seconds, Difference: 1.631105e-13
Size: 10000, Time (dot1p): 0.000299 seconds, Time (npdot1p): 0.000177 seconds, Difference: 1.622506e-12
Size: 100000, Time (dot1p): 0.004293 seconds, Time (npdot1p): 0.001869 seconds, Difference: 2.761014e-12
Size: 1000000, Time (dot1p): 0.028257 seconds, Time (npdot1p): 0.014261 seconds, Difference: 2.968028e-10
Size: 10000000, Time (dot1p): 0.175802 seconds, Time (npdot1p): 0.103509 seconds, Difference: 8.228977e-09
Size: 100000000, Time (dot1p): 1.700164 seconds, Time (npdot1p): 0.999349 seconds, Difference: 8.626604e-08
```

[image: Plot of running time of dot1p and npdot1p with respect to input size]

Comment: Why not simply use the fact that $v = \exp(\log(v+1)) - 1$?

Comment: @VHarisop I forgot to mention that there is another step of normalization which scales the entire matrix. It might lead to small numbers whose multiplication would underflow on a computer. It is preferable to sum the logarithms instead.